# gwt-voices - wav file not playing

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, audio

I followed this gwt-voices quickstart https://code.google.com/p/gwt-voices/wiki/GettingStarted to create and run simple gwt-voices project.
My problem is that the sound is not played when I run my project (Firefox) and I don't know why.
This my code:

```
public class GWTProject implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        SoundController soundController = new SoundController();
        Sound sound = soundController.createSound(Sound.MIME_TYPE_AUDIO_WAV_PCM,
        "C:/path/to/the/file/bienvenue.wav");

        sound.play();
        System.out.println(sound);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be putting the audio file relative to the war directory in your gwt app.
Say you put your wav file in MyProject/war/audio/bienvenue.wav

You code, will be now

```
  SoundController soundController = new SoundController();
    Sound sound = soundController.createSound(Sound.MIME_TYPE_AUDIO_WAV_PCM,
    "audio/bienvenue.wav");

    sound.play();
    System.out.println(sound);
```

Comment: Hi again,

That solved my problem thank you :-)

Now I'm trying to write a GWT client that lists some wav files and gives the user the possibility to play/stop them.
The files are stored in a database.
How can I play my wav files if the only way to do it is to put them in the war directory?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean the audio file is stored as a blob? or just the filename is stored. If it is stored as a blob, then you need to make a servlet that is mapped in your web.xml. Your servlet would only need to extract the audio file from your database and stream it out to the client, something like: 
      response.setContentType("audio/vnd.wave:");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println(<blobDataFromDatabase>);

Comment: You're right it wasn't clear.
The database contains the file name, something like: bievenue.wav.
The file itself is stored somewhere in the server let's say something like: /home/user/upload/bieveneue.wav.
So my servlet can retrieve the file name from the database and list it in the gwt client.
So how can I play them once they are listed? DO I need to write another servlet just to play/stop the wav files?

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like that https://gwt-voices.appspot.com/VoicesDemo.html

Comment: It looks like, you need a file servlet.